# Java & Mapstruct serialization with recursion

Tags: java, mapstruct

For some context, I am developing a Java Web application with Spring & Lombok (Rest API, controllers, etc).

And for JSON API responses I am using Mapstruct to perform the serializations between internal models and the final external ones.

But I cannot figure out how to parse the following example:

Where we can have a **Tree**.

```
public class Tree {
    List<Leaf> leafs;
}
```

And inside of it we have Leafs. **But each Leaf as inside of it a list of Leafs.**

```
public class Leaf {
    String name;
    List<Leaf> children;
}
```

So what I would need Mapstruct to do is, serialize the **Tree** into a **TreeResponse**.

```
public class TreeResponse {
    List<LeafResponse> leafs;
}
```

And all Leafs inside the Tree into **LeafResponse**, along with the Leaf list inside the "father" Leaf.

```
public class LeafResponse {
    String name;
    List<LeafResponse> children;
}
```

How can I achieve this in Mapstruct? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving all classes and simple test that finally worked.

Tree.java

```
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = PUBLIC)
public class Tree {
    String name;
    List<Leaf> leafs;
}
```

Leaf.java

```
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = PUBLIC)
public class Leaf {
    String name;
    List<Leaf> children;
}
```

TreeResponse.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldDefaults(level = PUBLIC)
public class TreeResponse {
    String name;
    List<LeafResponse> leafs;
}
```

LeafResponse.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldDefaults(level = PUBLIC)
public class LeafResponse {
    String name;
    List<LeafResponse> children;
}
```

Mappers

```
@Mapper
public interface TreeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "name", source = "entity.name")
    TreeResponse map(Tree entity);
}

@Mapper
public interface LeafMapperSecond {
    LeafResponse map(Leaf entity);

    List<LeafResponse> map(List<Leaf> entity);
}
```

Test

```
private TreeMapper treeMapper = Mappers.getMapper(TreeMapper.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Leaf> leafs = new ArrayList<>();
        leafs.add(Leaf.builder().name("Leaf 1").build());

        leafs.add(
                Leaf.builder()
                        .name("Leaf 2")
                        .children(
                                Arrays.asList(
                                        Leaf.builder()
                                                .name("Leaf Children 1")
                                                .children(
                                                        Arrays.asList(
                                                                Leaf.builder()
                                                                        .name("Leaf Children 1.1")
                                                                        .build(),
                                                                Leaf.builder()
                                                                        .name("Leaf Children 1.2")
                                                                        .build()))
                                                .build(),
                                        Leaf.builder().name("Leaf Children 2").build()))
                        .build());

        Tree tree = Tree.builder().name("tree name").leafs(leafs).build();

        TreeResponse treeResponse = treeMapper.map(tree);

        assertEquals(treeResponse.name, "tree name");
        assertEquals(treeResponse.leafs.size(), 2);

        LeafResponse leafWithChildren =
                treeResponse.leafs.stream()
                        .filter(l -> l.name.equals("Leaf 2"))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(null);
        assertNotNull(leafWithChildren);
        assertEquals(leafWithChildren.getChildren().size(), 2);

        LeafResponse leafWithSubChildren =
                leafWithChildren.children.stream()
                        .filter(l -> l.name.equals("Leaf Children 1"))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElse(null);
        
        assertNotNull(leafWithSubChildren);
        assertEquals(leafWithChildren.getChildren().size(), 2);
    }
```